# Bad request while trying to access Github's v4 API with graphql.js

Tags: javascript, graphql, github-api, graphql-js, github-graphql

I am trying to retrieve some data from Github's GraphQL API using graphql.js library.

```
var graph = graphql("https://api.github.com/graphql", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer <my-token-here>",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  fragments: {
    rateLimitInfo: "on RateLimit {cost,remaining,resetAt}"
  }
});
graph(`
    query repo($name: String!, $owner: String!){
        repository(name:$name, owner:$owner){
            id      
        }
    }
`,{
    name: "freeCodeCamp",
    owner: "freeCodeCamp"
}).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

My promise is not being fulfilled and always failing. I am getting an HTTP response with code **400 (Bad Request)** and the `error` argument of the `catch` function reads:

```
{
    message: "Problems parsing JSON", 
    documentation_url: "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

I have already tried passing the variables as JSON, like so:

```
{
    "name": "freeCodeCamp",
    "owner": "freeCodeCamp"
}
```

But it didn't help. I got the same bad request.

Looking at the Network tab of Chrome's inspector I see what the request payload is. Adding it here in case it give any clues or help.

```
query=query%20repo(%24name%3A%20String!%2C%20%24owner%3A%20String!)%7Brepository(name%3A%24name%2C%20owner%3A%24owner)%7Bid%7D%7D&variables=%7B%22name%22%3A%22freeCodeCamp%22%2C%22owner%22%3A%22freeCodeCamp%22%7D
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like the form the graphql.js is forming the data payload is not in the format that the Github API expects.

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour of [graphql.js](https://github.com/f/graphql.js) is to send the body in form-url-encoded format whereas Github GraphQL api accepts only JSON format. From [graphql.js readme](https://github.com/f/graphql.js#change-post-method) :

> As default, GraphQL.js makes a POST request. But you can change the
>   behavior by setting asJSON.
>
> ```
> var graph = graphql("http://localhost:3000/graphql", {   
>     asJSON: true
> });
> ```

You can see the difference [here](https://github.com/f/graphql.js/blob/c8631faac6c570720082ce5368a3d012f05e40a2/graphql.js#L38-L42)

The following will work as expected :

```
var graph = graphql("https://api.github.com/graphql", {
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
  },
  asJSON: true
});
graph(`
    query repo($name: String!, $owner: String!){
        repository(name:$name, owner:$owner){
            id      
        }
    }
`, {
  name: "freeCodeCamp",
  owner: "freeCodeCamp"
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: I tried to run your code from html file but it doesn't seem to work. [Asked](https://github.com/f/graphql.js/issues/47) the folks maintaining GraphQL.js but no response. Any idea why it would fail?